# How do I stop a Python Ray Cluster

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ray

I've been looking through the documentation, and I can't find any way to stop Ray after an answer is calculated within a tolerance level. Right now I'm writing the answer to a csv with a print('Ok to stop'), and then I kill the process manually. I'd like to stop all of the workers, and then have it automatically move on to another problem. Is there an error that I can raise that will make all of the workers stop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Have a line in your Python code to break the process if a condition is met and then shutdown your Ray instance:

```
ray.init()

....
if tolerance_level > 50:
    break

ray.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you start a ray cluster with ray.init, the cluster should be killed when your python program exists. If you start it with `ray start`, you can use the `ray stop` command to shutdown the cluster. You can also use `ray stop --force` to forcefully kill all processes left.

Comment: I don't want to wait for the python program to finish if it has found an acceptable value. I'm starting the cluster with ray.init(), and I was hoping there way a way to stop ray from within the python program.

Comment: Same issue here, from within a single python process I need to start and stop clusters at several point in the workflow and there doesn't seem to be a mechanism to do this? ray.shutdown() doesn't seem to fully remove the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

To stop a Ray cluster from Python, you can use `ray.shutdown()`.

Comment: Before running `ray.shutdown()` you can check if ray is running at all with `if ray.is_initialized():`